# Scrapy/XPath extract text from different tags (<p> OR <li>)

Tags: python, html, xpath, extract, mixed

I'm trying to scrape text from a website. Sometimes, the text is written in bullet points, sometimes just in plain text.

Text in Bullet points (XPath): `/article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]/ul/li[1]`

Text in Plain text (XPath): `/article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]/p`

I need the respectice text to be extracted (without div/ul/li/p tags etc). This is what I have tried so far:

`info_Aufgabengebiet = info.xpath(".//article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1][descendant::text()]").extract()`

Output: see image [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSYy1.png)

I also experimented with descendant-or-self, a /text() at the end, but neither worked. Simply, I want to extract all text no matter in bullet point or plain text. Pullet points should just be added, maybe with a ";" or ",".

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath with combined conditions

```
"/article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]/ul/li[1] | /article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]/p"
```

Answer (score 2):

The union operator `|` mentioned in the other answer is a good solution. Alternately, depending on your output needs, you might try

`/article/div[@class='border-bottom-grau'][1]//*[self::p or self::li]`